# Lemma 5.5 of Stein complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation

I have a question on the proof of Stein complex analysis Lemma 5.5

> Suppose $g$ is entire and $u = Re(g)$ satifies
> \begin{align*}
> u(z)\leq Cr^s\ \text{whenever}\ |z| = r\\
> \end{align*}
> for a sequence of positive real numbers $r$ that tends to infinity. Then $g$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq s$.

Proof. Expand $g$ in a power series centered at $0$:
$$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n.$$
By Cauchy integral formula, we get
$${1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g(re^{i\theta})e^{-in\theta}d\theta =\begin{cases}
a_nr^n & n\geq 0\\
0 & n<0\\
\end{cases}$$
$\color{red}{\text{By taking complex conjugates we find that}}$
$$\color{red}{{1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{g(re^{i\theta})}e^{-in\theta}d\theta = 0}$$
whenever $n>0$, ...

Why does the highlited statement hold?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the Cauchy integral formula you get
$$
 {1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g(re^{i\theta})e^{-in\theta}d\theta = 0
$$
for $n < 0$. The complex conjugate of the left-hand side is
$$
\overline{{1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g(re^{i\theta})e^{-in\theta}d\theta}
= {1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{g(re^{i\theta})e^{-in\theta}}d\theta =
{1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{g(re^{i\theta})}e^{in\theta}d\theta \, ,
$$
so we have
$$
{1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{g(re^{i\theta})}e^{in\theta}d\theta = 0
$$
for $n < 0$, or equivalently,
$$
{1\over 2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\overline{g(re^{i\theta})}e^{-in\theta}d\theta = 0
$$
for $n > 0$.